# UIViewController with ContainerView and UIView

Tags: uiview, pickerview

I am very new to iOS Programming. I am trying to develop a simple application where I have a difficulty to add pickerview to label action in TableViewController with static cells. So I am trying to use a UIViewController which has container view and UIView and container view contains TableViewController with different labels in cells and when touch on any label I want to show UIPickerView on UIView will that be possible? If so, how to acheive it? [image]

Comment: hi @Haritha and welcome to StackOverflow. I should say I don't know anything about IOS development but as a reviewer on SO I would like to refer you to the guidelines on ˋ[ask]ˋ - if you haven't read it already it should give you some good feedback on how to increase your chances of getting an answer to your question :-)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.